# VBA looping over cells

Tags: vba

I have some code working which replaces the values of cells if they are numeric and not empty. How can I amend the code to only replace the values if they are also not in ("2012", "2013", 2012, 2013)?

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
For Each cell In rng
  If IsNumeric(cell) And Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
    cell.Value = "max"
  End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Add a nested if inside the first. `If Not (cell = 2012 or cell = 2013 or ...) then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're really just doing a few more evaluations on the same cell, you can just "and them" together to keep it simple.

```
If IsNumeric(cell) And Not IsEmpty(cell) AND cell <> 2012 AND cell <> 2013 Then
```

Comment: `2012<>"2012"` but both with return true in IsNumeric.  And cell can certainly equal a number, as the default child of cell is `cell.Value`

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner . I've had my head in Word vba lately. I updated my answer, it works for me.